# AEM query builder: search multiple properties

Tags: aem, query-builder, aem-6

How can I list all the properties and respective values for more than one property under a give node.

For example, the below code, I could search for one property only. But I need to search for 10 different property(alttext, img, promos.. etc) and get respective values(if exist) for it.

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TYPE_PREDICATE, "nt:base");
                    map.put(PATH_PREDICATE, printAttachmentJsonNodePath);
                    map.put("property", "fileReference");
                    map.put("p.excerpt", "true");
                    map.put(SEARCH_LIMIT_PREDICATE, "-1");

                    Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),
                            resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
                    SearchResult result = query.getResult();

                    for (Hit hit : result.getHits()) {
                        String path = hit.getPath();
                        Resource resourceHit = resourceResolver.getResource(path);

                            Node node = resourceHit.adaptTo(Node.class);


                            String fileReference = node.getProperty("fileReference").getString();
                            System.out.println(fileReference);
                    }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use numerical prefixes for multiple properties:

```
map.put("1_property", "jcr:content/cq:template");
map.put("1_property.value", "/apps/geometrixx/templates/homepage");
map.put("2_property", "jcr:content/jcr:title");
map.put("2_property.value", "English");
```

here is [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of properties, or amount of properties is generated during runtime you could use [Predicate.class](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/Predicate.html)

Your code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TYPE_PREDICATE, "nt:base");
map.put(PATH_PREDICATE, printAttachmentJsonNodePath);
map.put("property", "fileReference");
map.put("p.excerpt", "true");
map.put(SEARCH_LIMIT_PREDICATE, "-1");

Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),
        resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

Will looks in the following way:

```
PredicateGroup rootGroup = new PredicateGroup();
rootGroup.add(new Predicate("type").set("type", "nt:base"));
rootGroup.add(new Predicate("path").set("path", printAttachmentJsonNodePath));
rootGroup.add(new Predicate("property").set(property, "fileReference"));
rootGroup.add(new Predicate("property").set(property, "property1").set("value", value1));
.....
rootGroup.add(new Predicate("property").set(property, "propertyN").set("value", valueN));
rootGroup.set(Predicate.PARAM_EXCERPT, Boolean.TRUE.toString());
rootGroup.set(Predicate.PARAM_LIMIT, "-1");

Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(rootGroup);
query.setHitsPerPage(limit); // also you could put limit here

SearchResult result = query.getResult();
...........
```

In this case AND condition will be created betwean properties : `@property1=value1 AND @property2=value2`

If you want OR, create separate group and add it to the root group:

```
PredicateGroup properties = new PredicateGroup();
properties.add(new Predicate("property").set(property, "property1").set("value", value1));
.....
properties.add(new Predicate("property").set(property, "propertyN").set("value", valueN));
properties.setAllRequired(false);

rootGroup.add(properties);
```