# AEM Query-builder query in batch

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have the below working query

```
path=/content/dam
type=sling:OrderedFolder
nodename=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
property=jcr:content/metadataprofile
property.operation=exists
property.value=false
p.limit=-1
```

It runs on entire **Path=/content/dam**, so it traverse all nodes for about 20 minutes and gives results.

How can i make it in batches when using query-builder api programatically, like - traverse 1000 nodes and *do-something code-wise* and then continue with query and traversing next 1000 nodes and so-on ?  Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find pagination approach here : https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html

Comment: @cylinder.y could you provide any link for pagination sample code ?

Comment: you may look into my old answer here ^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505913/aem-query-builder-search-multiple-properties/51589561#51589561

Comment: and here pagination is used : https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html#ExampleQueryBuilderAPIUsage

Answer (score 0):

You may use pagination approach from here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html#ExampleQueryBuilderAPIUsage

Pagination is configured in the following way:

```
// can be done in map or with Query methods
map.put("p.offset", "0"); // same as query.setStart(0) below
map.put("p.limit", "20"); // same as query.setHitsPerPage(20) below
```

or

```
query.setStart(0);
query.setHitsPerPage(20);
```

and go throught result in a loop:

```
// iterating over the results
for (Hit hit : result.getHits()) {
    String path = hit.getPath();
    ......
}
```

For more details, please has a look into `Implementing pagination` on the page provided above.